# How to prevent Denial of Service (DoS) using IIS?

Tags: http, iis, web, webserver

I've detected that some IPs perform **lots of requests** to my Website. I want to block these massive requests, because they generate a lot of traffic. I used the [IIS address and domain restrictions](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity) to block these IPs:

[image: domain restrictions on IIS]

This method requires that I monitor IIS every day and add a rule manually. Is there any feature in IIS, or any best practice to perform this task automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DOS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) cannot be prevented at web server level. It requires a commercial firewall, or cloud based services such as [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com/features-security).

Like you discovered, manual configuration on IIS, or any simple scripting won't save you from that.